# JSF: Upload and passing an xlsx file to my JavaBean Method

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I need to upload an xlsx file in my jsf application and send it to my Javabean method, so I started using :

```
<rich:fileUpload
  fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
  maxFilesQuantity="#{fileUploadBean.uploadsAvailable}"
  id="upload"
  immediateUpload="#{fileUploadBean.autoUpload}"
  acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp" allowFlash=#  {fileUploadBean.useFlash}
 <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="info" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

But Its not working and  I don't clearly understand why.
Could you please give me a complete example with a configuration of web.xml,  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't your `acceptedTypes` include xlsx?

Comment: Yes I did it but it doesn't work :  acceptedTypes="xlsx,xls"